# .APK file is not uploading for PayPal classic application creation

Tags: android, paypal, apk

I have developed an Android App with PayPal integration, Now to obtain Live PayPal AppID for PayPal Classic APIs, i am trying to fill up the form on PayPal and has to upload .apk file to PayPal under "Additional Testing Files (Ad Hoc files required for mobile app submissions)." heading. However it is not allowing me to upload .APK file, it only allows doc, png, pdf, docx extension files to upload.

It was not like that before, i think during recent changes they have changed few things here as well. Can anyone help me and advice about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe there were some additional restrictions around possible file types. We'll see if we can improve on this.

In the meantime I would suggest including a link to your .apk on a Dropbox-type service / direct link on your server on which we can access it.

Comment: This is what [B@420e0f58 they are returning from APP to Web service, so when i got this, i am not able to convert it to an image. Any clue ?